# Chain queuing callbacks results

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, callback, promise

I got a loop like this:

```
for ( var current in all )
{
    //load the item
    prepare.load( all[current].resource , function( result ) { 
         doSomethingWithResult(result);
    });
}

function AllItemsLoaded()
{
}
```

My goal is to execute AllItemsLoaded() after all items are loaded and the code in the callbacks is executed, e.g. For every item callback should be called and DoSomethingWithResult() should be executed before AllItemsLoaded() is called, all these items are loaded asynchronously.

I've tried Jquery Deferred/pipe and my code looked like this:

```
var chain = new $.Deferred().resolve();

for ( var current in all )
{
                chain = chain.pipe(function(res){
                prepare.load( all[current].resource , function( result ) { 
                     doSomethingWithResult(result);
                });
            });
 //if I do a return here, the pipe will continue without getting the result, 
so I need to continue the pipe after load's callback and 
doSomethingWithResult is executed

}

chain.done(AllItemsLoaded);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deferred is a good idea. However, you need to wait on the promise. Here's a method using when to wait on all the promises without doing them in order:

```
var loads = [];

for ( var current in all )
{
        (function(){
    var deferred = new $.Deferred();
    prepare.load( all[current].resource , function( result ) { 
         doSomethingWithResult(result);
         deferred.resolve(result);
    });
    loads.push(deferred.promise());
        })();
}

$.when.apply(null, loads).then(AllItemsLoaded);
```

First create a new deferred for each load. Place its promise in a collection. After the load, resolve the deferred. Wait on all of the loads with $.when().

Comment: I like your answer the most, but I got a problem. AllItemsLoaded is executed instantly, before resolve() is called.

Comment: @Deepsy I am not at a computer now, but I think when doesn't take an array. I should've used $.when.apply. I'll try it when I get to a computer.

Comment: @Deepsy it looks like apply wasn't the only problem. I also needed to create a new scope so that the deferred variable isn't shared. Here's the fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/5vcqQ/1/

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

From: http://aabs.wordpress.com/2009/12/16/sequential-script-loading-on-demand/

```
function LoadScriptsSequentially(scriptUrls, callback)
{
    if (typeof scriptUrls == 'undefined') throw "Argument Error: URL array is unusable";
    if (scriptUrls.length == 0 && typeof callback == 'function') callback();
    $.getScript(scriptUrls.shift(), function() { LoadScriptsSequentially(scriptUrls, callback); });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it as such (below), where you replace each `$.get()` with your own asynchronous object, with it's own individual complete handler.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.when( 
        $.get("ajax.php?a=b"), 
        $.get("ajax.php?a=c"), 
        $.get("ajax.php?a=d")                   
    ).then(
        function() {
                // both AJAX calls have succeeded
                alert("All Done");
        }, 
        function() {
                // one of the AJAX calls has failed
                alert("One or more failed");
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing is to use `.get()` or `.post()` not `.load()`, the reason being that `.load()` returns jQuery while the other two return jqXHR (ie a promise), which is what you want here.

Next thing is to provide an array in which to accumulate the jqXHR promises.

Last you need to know how to get `$.when()` to act on the array of promises, to do something when all of them are resolved (or an error occurs).

The whole thing looks like this :

```
var promises = [];//new Array

for ( var current in all ) {
    prepare.get( all[current].resource, function( result ) {
         doSomethingWithResult(result);
    });
}

$.when.apply(null, promises).then(AllItemsLoaded, myErrorHandler);
```